# Getting the average of each 2 elements on a list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of numbers. (I will give an example down below.) I wanted to understand how to sum 1st and 3rd element, 3rd and 4th element and divide by them half. Homever each time I change the values with a loop for example, the new i value takes place for the considered loop so, all my values get messed up. I am leaving the code I have tried down below for this to work.

```
for i in liste6:
    liste6[i]=((liste6[i]+liste6[i+2])/2)
```

Also this doesn't work on float values the values I have are 10.0 not floats entirely but floats by concept.

What I have:

```
[10.0, 10.0, 40.0, 40.0, 60.0, 10.0, 90.0, 40.0]
```

Desired:

```
[25.0, 25.0, 75.0, 25.0]
```

Note: The list is changing but this is the main issue.

Edit: I am sorry, I didn't clarify how you got the second list from the first one.
For each 4 elements I want to get the average of the 1st and the 3rd elements for in this case 10 and 40, 10 and 40. On the other 4 element set (the average of 60,90 and 10 and 40.

I am very sorry for the bad explanation .
Have a great day

Comment: It's not clear how you got the second list from the first.

Comment: The question title says "each 2 elements" which means the result list should get bigger while in your case its gets smaller

Comment: for i in liste6 should be for i in range(liste6)?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a for-each loop in the way you'd use a for loop, it's either

```
for item in lst:
    # item: item
```

or

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    # item: lst[i]
```

For this purpose I think a for loop would be more appropriate, but going through the whole range of indexes will result in out of bounds errors, so the right code would look something like this:

```
output = []
for i in range(len(lst)-1):
    output.append((lst[i] + lst[i + 1])/2)
```

This way you would get a list filled with the averages in the `output` variable.